# Set text of a control of a child-window in WPF

Tags: wpf, controls, parent

How can i set a text of a textblock of a child window. childWindowname.textblockName.Text = "" doesn't have any effect.

Comment: It might sound like a stupid question, but are you sure the TextBlock is visible, there are no issues with styles whereby the foreground and background colours could be the same etc?  Have you tried running Snoop over the application to inspect the TextBlock at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odd.  I have used Text from codebehind to change the text in my window without any problems.  The only difference is that I had a public method in my child window that I called, and that set textblockname.Text.

e.g.

```
public void SetTextBlockMessage(string message)
{
  textblockname.Text = message;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did it the same way, but there wasn't any effect.